# Exception caught by image resource service error

Tags: android, ios, flutter

Hello friend   i am using youtube player plugin for playing youtube video i also fetch some thumbnail from youtube link problem is that when  i am trying playing youtube video its working fine on Android but on iphone its not playing on full sacreen mode i try get log i recieved this log in console.in DetailPage if news type is image it fetch image if it type is video its fetch all youtube video thumbnails its working fine and fetching all thubnails but give exception my concern is not resolve this exception my concern it playing full video on ios

```
════════ Exception caught by image resource service ════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following assertion was thrown resolving an image codec:


 Unable to load asset: assets/ypf.png
    
    When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
    #0      PlatformAssetBundle.load (package:flutter/src/services/asset_bundle.dart:221:7)
    <asynchronous suspension>
    #1      AssetBundleImageProvider._loadAsync (package:flutter/src/painting/image_provider.dart:664:31)
    #2      AssetBundleImageProvider.load (package:flutter/src/painting/image_provider.dart:648:14)
    #3      ImageProvider.resolveStreamForKey.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/painting/image_provider.dart:501:13)
    ...
    Image provider: AssetImage(bundle: null, name: "assets/ypf.png")
    Image key: AssetBundleImageKey(bundle: PlatformAssetBundle#5acb7(), name: "assets/ypf.png", scale: 1.0)
    ════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
    
    ════════ Exception caught by image resource service ════════════════════════════════════════════════
    The following NetworkImageLoadException was thrown resolving an image codec:
    HTTP request failed, statusCode: 404, https://img.youtube.com/vi/https://img.youtube.com/vi/https://img.youtube.com/vi/exbwhvgPIyo/hqdefault.jpg/hqdefault.jpg/hqdefault.jpg
    
    When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
    #0      NetworkImage._loadAsync (package:flutter/src/painting/_network_image_io.dart:95:9)
    <asynchronous suspension>
    #1      NetworkImage.load (package:flutter/src/painting/_network_image_io.dart:48:14)
    #2      ImageProvider.resolveStreamForKey.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/painting/image_provider.dart:501:13)
    #3      ImageCache.putIfAbsent (package:flutter/src/painting/image_cache.dart:359:22)
    ...
    Image provider: NetworkImage("https://img.youtube.com/vi/https://img.youtube.com/vi/https://img.youtube.com/vi/exbwhvgPIyo/hqdefault.jpg/hqdefault.jpg/hqdefault.jpg", scale: 1.0)
    Image key: NetworkImage("https://img.youtube.com/vi/https://img.youtube.com/vi/https://img.youtube.com/vi/exbwhvgPIyo/hqdefault.jpg/hqdefault.jpg/hqdefault.jpg", scale: 1.0)
```

════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

```
════════ Exception caught by image resource service ════════════════════════════════════════════════
HTTP request failed, statusCode: 404, https://img.youtube.com/vi/https://img.youtube.com/vi/https://img.youtube.com/vi/uYCshzLDOpA/hqdefault.jpg/hqdefault.jpg/hqdefault.jpg
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ Exception caught by image resource service ════════════════════════════════════════════════
HTTP request failed, statusCode: 404, https://img.youtube.com/vi/https://img.youtube.com/vi/https://img.youtube.com/vi/5yzW1r0zXQI/hqdefault.jpg/hqdefault.jpg/hqdefault.jpg
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ Exception caught by image resource service ════════════════════════════════════════════════
HTTP request failed, statusCode: 404, https://img.youtube.com/vi/https://img.youtube.com/vi/https://img.youtube.com/vi/D6ACmdU3jas/hqdefault.jpg/hqdefault.jpg/hqdefault.jpg
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ Exception caught by image resource service ════════════════════════════════════════════════
HTTP request failed, statusCode: 404, https://img.youtube.com/vi/https://img.youtube.com/vi/https://img.youtube.com/vi/qGaQso9SvPY/hqdefault.jpg/hqdefault.jpg/hqdefault.jpg
═════════════════════════════════════════════════
HTTP request failed, statusCode: 404, https://img.youtube.com/vi/https://img.youtube.com/vi/https://img.youtube.com/vi/IKHsljZg3as/hqdefault.jpg/hqdefault.jpg/hqdefault.jpg
```

════════ Exception caught by image resource service ════════════════════════════════════════════════
HTTP request failed, statusCode: 404, https://img.youtube.com/vi/https://img.youtube.com/vi/https://img.youtube.com/vi/SWw62MlahFw/hqdefault.jpg/hqdefault.jpg/hqdefault.jpg
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

```
════════ Exception caught by image resource service ════════════════════════════════════════════════
HTTP request failed, statusCode: 404, https://img.youtube.com/vi/https://img.youtube.com/vi/https://img.youtube.com/vi/tWjW0tupH44/hqdefault.jpg/hqdefault.jpg/hqdefault.jpg
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ Exception caught by image resource service ════════════════════════════════════════════════
HTTP request failed, statusCode: 404, https://img.youtube.com/vi/https://img.youtube.com/vi/https://img.youtube.com/vi/Q6W0QOJuGWs/hqdefault.jpg/hqdefault.jpg/hqdefault.jpg
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ Exception caught by image resource service ════════════════════════════════════════════════
HTTP request failed, statusCode: 404, https://img.youtube.com/vi/https://img.youtube.com/vi/https://img.youtube.com/vi/https://img.youtube.com/vi/uYCshzLDOpA/hqdefault.jpg/hqdefault.jpg/hqdefault.jpg/hqdefault.jpg
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ Exception caught by image resource service ════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following NetworkImageLoadException was thrown resolving an image codec:
HTTP request failed, statusCode: 404, https://img.youtube.com/vi/https://img.youtube.com/vi/https://img.youtube.com/vi/https://img.youtube.com/vi/esuLRQjD6fU/hqdefault.jpg/hqdefault.jpg/hqdefault.jpg/hqdefault.jpg

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
#0      NetworkImage._loadAsync (package:flutter/src/painting/_network_image_io.dart:95:9)
<asynchronous suspension>
#1      NetworkImage.load (package:flutter/src/painting/_network_image_io.dart:48:14)
#2      ImageProvider.resolveStreamForKey.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/painting/image_provider.dart:501:13)
#3      ImageCache.putIfAbsent (package:flutter/src/painting/image_cache.dart:359:22)
...
Image provider: NetworkImage("https://img.youtube.com/vi/https://img.youtube.com/vi/https://img.youtube.com/vi/https://img.youtube.com/vi/esuLRQjD6fU/hqdefault.jpg/hqdefault.jpg/hqdefault.jpg/hqdefault.jpg", scale: 1.0)
Image key: NetworkImage("https://img.youtube.com/vi/https://img.youtube.com/vi/https://img.youtube.com/vi/https://img.youtube.com/vi/esuLRQjD6fU/hqdefault.jpg/hqdefault.jpg/hqdefault.jpg/hqdefault.jpg", scale: 1.0)
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ Exception caught by image resource service ════════════════════════════════════════════════
HTTP request failed, statusCode: 404, https://img.youtube.com/vi/https://img.youtube.com/vi/https://img.youtube.com/vi/https://img.youtube.com/vi/5yzW1r0zXQI/hqdefault.jpg/hqdefault.jpg/hqdefault.jpg/hqdefault.jpg
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ Exception caught by image resource service ════════════════════════════════════════════════
HTTP request failed, statusCode: 404, https://img.youtube.com/vi/https://img.youtube.com/vi/https://img.youtube.com/vi/https://img.youtube.com/vi/5w7oFE06GyM/hqdefault.jpg/hqdefault.jpg/hqdefault.jpg/hqdefault.jpg
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ Exception caught by image resource service ════════════════════════════════════════════════
HTTP request failed, statusCode: 404, https://img.youtube.com/vi/https://img.youtube.com/vi/https://img.youtube.com/vi/https://img.youtube.com/vi/SWw62MlahFw/hqdefault.jpg/hqdefault.jpg/hqdefault.jpg/hqdefault.jpg
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ Exception caught by image resource service ════════════════════════════════════════════════
HTTP request failed, statusCode: 404, https://img.youtube.com/vi/https://img.youtube.com/vi/https://img.youtube.com/vi/https://img.youtube.com/vi/54DFanTEHQA/hqdefault.jpg/hqdefault.jpg/hqdefault.jpg/hqdefault.jpg
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ Exception caught by image resource service ════════════════════════════════════════════════
HTTP request failed, statusCode: 404, https://img.youtube.com/vi/https://img.youtube.com/vi/https://img.youtube.com/vi/https://img.youtube.com/vi/qGaQso9SvPY/hqdefault.jpg/hqdefault.jpg/hqdefault.jpg/hqdefault.jpg
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ Exception caught by image resource service ════════════════════════════════════════════════
HTTP request failed, statusCode: 404, https://img.youtube.com/vi/https://img.youtube.com/vi/https://img.youtube.com/vi/https://img.youtube.com/vi/QJl0AZGdneM/hqdefault.jpg/hqdefault.jpg/hqdefault.jpg/hqdefault.jpg
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ Exception caught by image resource service ════════════════════════════════════════════════
HTTP request failed, statusCode: 404, https://img.youtube.com/vi/https://img.youtube.com/vi/https://img.youtube.com/vi/https://img.youtube.com/vi/3V2KSFeabkM/hqdefault.jpg/hqdefault.jpg/hqdefault.jpg/hqdefault.jpg







         import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
        import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
        import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
        import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
        import 'dart:async';
        import 'dart:convert';
        import 'package:tv/ImageDetails.dart';
        import 'package:tv/video.dart';
        class DetailPage extends StatefulWidget {
          final String id;
          final String title;
          DetailPage(this.id, this.title);
        
          @override
          _DetailPageState createState() => _DetailPageState();
        }
        
        class _DetailPageState extends State<DetailPage> {
          bool _loading=true;
          Map data;
          List userData;
          String image;
        
        
          Future getData() async {
            String id=widget.id;
            http.Response response = await http.get("http://lhtvapp.com//api.php?cat_id=$id");
            data = json.decode(response.body);
            //debugPrint(response.body);
            print(id);
            setState(() {
              userData = data["NEWS_APP"];
              _loading=false;
            });
        
          }
          @override
          void initState() {
        
            // TODO: implement initState
            super.initState();
            getData();
          }
        
          @override
          Widget build(BuildContext context) {
            String title=widget.title;
            return Scaffold(
              appBar: AppBar(
                  backgroundColor:Colors.white,
                  automaticallyImplyLeading:true,
                  leading: IconButton(
        
                    icon:Icon(
                        Icons.arrow_back_ios,color: Colors.amber[800]),
                       onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(),
                  ),
                  elevation: 0.0,
                  title:Row(
        
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Image.asset(
                        'images/logo.png',
                        height: 100,
        
                      ),
        
        
                    ],
                  )
        
        
              ),
              body:_loading ? Center(
        
                child: Container(
                  child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                    valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(Colors.amber[800]),
                  ),
                ),
              ) :
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: Container(
                  child: Column(
        
                    children: <Widget>[
        
                      Text(title,style:TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 25,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold
                      ),),
                      SizedBox(height: 10,),
                      Text('So faith comes from hearing, and hearing through the word of Christ (Romans 10:17)'
        
        
                           ,style:TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.black54,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold
                      ),),
                      SizedBox(height: 10,),
        
                      Expanded(
                        child: GridView.builder(
                          padding:EdgeInsets.only(top:12),
                          shrinkWrap: true,
                          itemCount:userData == null ? 0 : userData.length,
                          gridDelegate:new SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(crossAxisCount: 3),
                          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context,int index){
                            String new_type=userData[index]['news_type'];
                            if(new_type=="image") {
        
                              image = userData[index]['news_image_b'];
                            }
                            else
                              {
                              String thumb=userData[index]['video_id'];
                              image=userData[index]['video_id']='https://img.youtube.com/vi/${thumb}/hqdefault.jpg';
        
        
                              }
                            return new GestureDetector(
        
                              onTap: (){
                           new_type=userData[index]['news_type'];
        
                              if(new_type=="image"){
                                String des=userData[index]['news_description'];
                                Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
                                  builder:(context)=>ImageDetails(userData[index]['id'],userData[index]['news_title'],userData[index]['news_image_s'],userData[index]['news_description']),
        
        
                                )
                                );
                              }else{
                                Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
                                  builder:(context)=>Video(userData[index]['video_url'],userData[index]['news_title'],userData[index]['news_description']),
        
        
        
                                )
                                );
                              }
        
        
        
                              },
                              child: new Card(
        
                                shape:RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                                ),
        
                                child: new Container(
        
                                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                                  child: Column(
        
                                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                                    children: <Widget>[
                                      Expanded
                                        (child:
                                      ClipRRect(
        
                                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                                          child: Image.network(image,fit: BoxFit.cover,))),
        
                                      Center(
                                        child: Container(
                                          child: Text(userData[index]["news_title"],style:TextStyle(
                                              fontSize:11,
                                              fontWeight:FontWeight.bold
        
        
                                          ),),
                                        ),
                                      )
        
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                ),
        
                              ),
                            );
        
        
                            },
        
        
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
        
        
                /*   child:GridView.builder(
                    itemCount: 20,
                    gridDelegate:new SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(crossAxisCount: 3),
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context,int index){
        return new GestureDetector(
          child: new Card(
        
            child: new Container(
        
                child: Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                  Text('Item $index')
                  ],
                ),
        0    ),
          ),
        );
                  },
        
        
                ),*/
              ),
            );
          }
        }
    
   
   
import 'dart:developer';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:youtube_player_flutter/youtube_player_flutter.dart';


/// Creates [YoutubePlayerDemoApp] widget.
class YoutubePlayerDemoApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Video('video','title','des'),
    );
  }
}

/// Homepage
class Video extends StatefulWidget {
  String videourl;
  String title;
  String des;
  @override
  _VideoState createState() => _VideoState();

  Video(this.videourl, this.title, this.des);


}

class _VideoState extends State<Video> {
  final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldKey = GlobalKey();
  YoutubePlayerController _controller;
  TextEditingController _idController;
  TextEditingController _seekToController;

  PlayerState _playerState;
  YoutubeMetaData _videoMetaData;
  double _volume = 100;
  bool _muted = false;
  bool _isPlayerReady = false;

  final List<String> _ids = [

  ];

  @override
  void initState() {
    WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
    super.initState();
    _controller = YoutubePlayerController(
      initialVideoId:YoutubePlayer.convertUrlToId(widget.videourl),
      flags: const YoutubePlayerFlags(
        mute: false,
        autoPlay: true,
        disableDragSeek: false,
        loop: false,
        isLive: false,
        forceHD: true,
        enableCaption: true,
      ),
    )..addListener(listener);
    _idController = TextEditingController();
    _seekToController = TextEditingController();
    _videoMetaData = const YoutubeMetaData();
    _playerState = PlayerState.unknown;
  }

  void listener() {
    if (_isPlayerReady && mounted && !_controller.value.isFullScreen) {
      setState(() {
        _playerState = _controller.value.playerState;
        _videoMetaData = _controller.metadata;
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  void deactivate() {
    // Pauses video while navigating to next page.
    _controller.pause();
    super.deactivate();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controller.dispose();
    _idController.dispose();
    _seekToController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return YoutubePlayerBuilder(
      onExitFullScreen: () {
        // The player forces portraitUp after exiting fullscreen. This overrides the behaviour.
        SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations(DeviceOrientation.values);
      },
      player: YoutubePlayer(
        controller: _controller,
        showVideoProgressIndicator: true,
        progressIndicatorColor: Colors.blueAccent,
        topActions: <Widget>[
          const SizedBox(width: 8.0),
          Expanded(
            child: Text(
              _controller.metadata.title,
              style: const TextStyle(
                color: Colors.white,
                fontSize: 18.0,
              ),
              overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
              maxLines: 1,
            ),
          ),

        ],
        onReady: () {
          _isPlayerReady = true;
        },
        onEnded: (data) {
          _controller
              .load(_ids[(_ids.indexOf(data.videoId) + 1) % _ids.length]);
          _showSnackBar('Next Video Started!');
        },
      ),
      builder: (context, player) => Scaffold(
        key: _scaffoldKey,
        appBar: AppBar(
            backgroundColor:Colors.white,
            automaticallyImplyLeading:true,
            leading: IconButton(
              icon:Icon(
                  Icons.arrow_back_ios,color: Colors.amber[800]),
              onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(),
            ),
            elevation: 0.0,
            title:Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                Image.asset(
                  'images/logo.png',
                  height: 100,

                ),


              ],
            )


        ),
        body: ListView(
          children: [
            player,
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                children: [
                  _space,
                  _text('Title', _videoMetaData.title

                  ),
                  _space,
                  _space,

                  _space,

                  _space,

                  _space,

                  _space,

                  _space,

                  _space,
                  AnimatedContainer(
                    duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 800),
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),

                    ),
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    child: Text(
                      _playerState.toString(),
                      style: const TextStyle(
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w300,
                        color: Colors.white,
                      ),
                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _text(String title, String value) {
    return RichText(
      text: TextSpan(
        text: '$title : ',
        style: const TextStyle(
          color: Colors.black,
          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
        ),
        children: [
          TextSpan(
            text: value ?? '',
            style: const TextStyle(
              color: Colors.black,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.w300,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

/*  Color _getStateColor(PlayerState state) {
    switch (state) {
      case PlayerState.unknown:
        return Colors.grey[700];
      case PlayerState.unStarted:
        return Colors.pink;
      case PlayerState.ended:
        return Colors.red;
      case PlayerState.playing:
        return Colors.blueAccent;
      case PlayerState.paused:
        return Colors.orange;
      case PlayerState.buffering:
        return Colors.yellow;
      case PlayerState.cued:
        return Colors.blue[900];
      default:
        return Colors.blue;
    }
  }*/

  Widget get _space => const SizedBox(height: 10);

  Widget _loadCueButton(String action) {
    return Expanded(
      child: MaterialButton(
        color: Colors.blueAccent,
        onPressed: _isPlayerReady
            ? () {
          if (_idController.text.isNotEmpty) {
            var id = YoutubePlayer.convertUrlToId(
              _idController.text,
            );
            if (action == 'LOAD') _controller.load(id);
            if (action == 'CUE') _controller.cue(id);
            FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(FocusNode());
          } else {
            _showSnackBar('Source can\'t be empty!');
          }
        }
            : null,
        disabledColor: Colors.grey,
        disabledTextColor: Colors.black,
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 14.0),
          child: Text(
            action,
            style: const TextStyle(
              fontSize: 18.0,
              color: Colors.white,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.w300,
            ),
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void _showSnackBar(String message) {
    _scaffoldKey.currentState.showSnackBar(
      SnackBar(
        content: Text(
          message,
          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          style: const TextStyle(
            fontWeight: FontWeight.w300,
            fontSize: 16.0,
          ),
        ),
        backgroundColor: Colors.blueAccent,
        behavior: SnackBarBehavior.floating,
        elevation: 1.0,
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50.0),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: @HBS i post look below the exception i posted my code

Comment: Post your code where you are implementing the `youtube_player`, we will look into this and see where is the problem

Comment: In the meantime, you can look into this video, I am sure it will help you resolve your problem: [Flutter YouTube API and Video Player Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=feQhHStBVLE). All the best